# Not showing faces, edges, vertices and background ref images

Tags: vertices, faces, edges

I worked well with making this M4A1. I added a background reference image too. But because of a mistake of mine, now the vertices, edges, faces while in edit mode and background ref images can not be seen. i dont know how this happened but as I think this happened due to key in keyboard. But I dont know how to fix this.[image: vertices, edges, faces cannot be seen in edit mode and the background ref image can't be seen.]

Comment: please share blend file

Comment: Turn on overlays in the upper right area of the viewport.

Comment: You have Viewport Overlays turned off. (Icon with dot and overlapping circle top right of viewport.)